# Yodlee addSiteAccount1 returns com.yodlee.core.IncompleteArgumentException

Tags: yodlee

My code is in Codeigniter using Restful api.

```
    $cobSessionToken=cobloginss();
    $userSession_Token=getUserToken();  

    $response        = array();

    $config = array(
        "url" => "https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1",
        "parameters" => array(
        "cobSessionToken" => $cobSessionToken,
        "userSessionToken" => $userSession_Token,
        "siteId" => $_POST['siteId'],
        "credentialFields.enclosedType" => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
        "credentialFields[0].displayName" => $_POST['credentialFields1_displayName'],
        "credentialFields[0].typeName" => $_POST['credentialFields1_fieldType_typeName'],
        "credentialFields[0].name" => $_POST['credentialFields1_name'],
        "credentialFields[0].value" => $_POST['credentialFields'][0],
        "credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier" => $_POST['credentialFields1_valueIdentifier'],
        "credentialFields[0].valueMask" => $_POST['credentialFields1_valueMask'],
        "credentialFields[0].isEditable" => $_POST['credentialFields1_isEditable'],

        "credentialFields[0].helpText" => $_POST['credentialFields1_helpText'],
        "credentialFields[0].maxlength" => $_POST['credentialFields1_maxlength'],
        "credentialFields[0].size" => $_POST['credentialFields1_size'],

        "credentialFields[1].displayName" => $_POST['credentialFields2_displayName'],
        "credentialFields[1].typeName" => $_POST['credentialFields2_fieldType_typeName'],
        "credentialFields[1].name" => $_POST['credentialFields2_name'],
        "credentialFields[1].value" => $_POST['credentialFields'][1],
        "credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier" => $_POST['credentialFields2_valueIdentifier'],
        "credentialFields[1].valueMask" => $_POST['credentialFields2_valueMask'],
        "credentialFields[1].isEditable" => $_POST['credentialFields2_isEditable'],

        "credentialFields[1].helpText" => $_POST['credentialFields2_helpText'],
        "credentialFields[1].maxlength" => $_POST['credentialFields2_maxlength'],
        "credentialFields[1].size" => $_POST['credentialFields2_size']
    )
    );
```

this looks like as follows when i do print_r($config)

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1
    [parameters] => Array
        (
            [cobSessionToken] => 08062013_0:52e7099efa26aa3393dacc1d237ad3b53609041d8f82188491fb9c70764e20e05c63e3e7e1850dfc7913bbf54a5c7880f14531fc71e234d24200a51812b992e0
            [userSessionToken] => 08062013_0:0588a3039977888a5d3f49a741b43b0d3e9aa9325b8daa444de6f31f3008f1481d9faa0a301d75173f42a6c84d824cd9467ec8634f45ae60f987c7d2c28fb8f7
            [siteId] => 3345
            [credentialFields.enclosedType] => com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
            [credentialFields[0].displayName] => User ID
            [credentialFields[0].typeName] => IF_LOGIN
            [credentialFields[0].name] => LOGIN
            [credentialFields[0].value] => dustingyoder
            [credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier] => LOGIN
            [credentialFields[0].valueMask] => LOGIN_FIELD
            [credentialFields[0].isEditable] => true
            [credentialFields[0].helpText] => 53224
            [credentialFields[0].maxlength] => 40
            [credentialFields[0].size] => 20
            [credentialFields[1].displayName] => Password
            [credentialFields[1].typeName] => IF_PASSWORD
            [credentialFields[1].name] => PASSWORD
            [credentialFields[1].value] => Dus08Yod1985
            [credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier] => PASSWORD
            [credentialFields[1].valueMask] => LOGIN_FIELD
            [credentialFields[1].isEditable] => true
            [credentialFields[1].helpText] => 53223
            [credentialFields[1].maxlength] => 40
            [credentialFields[1].size] => 20
        )

)
```

and the final response is

```
Array
(
    [Body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [errorOccurred] => true
            [exceptionType] => com.yodlee.core.IncompleteArgumentException
            [referenceCode] => _08ddcbd6-7d93-4365-9ee0-e3555ca181f9
            [message] => Incomplete argument: FieldInfoSingle: {FieldInfo: name="null" displayName="null" editable=false optional=false helpText="null" valuePattern="null" } defaultValue="null" value="null" validValues=[null] displayValidValues=[null] valueIdentifier="PASSWORD" valueMask="LOGIN_FIELD" fieldType="null" validationRules=[null] size=null maxlength=null userProfileMappingExpression=null fieldErrorCode=null fieldErrorMessage=null 
        )

)
```

Can anyone please Let me know what i did the mistake is

Answer (score 0):

It was just arguments were missing in the service, I found those arguments in firebug console thanks for firebug.. Altogether 32 arguments needs to be passed I passed only 24 arguments so problem solved by passing remaining parameters(arguments) to the web service

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you to pass all the arguments which are mandatory as well as which are optional though applicable depending upon the use case.

It's great that you have already identified the root cause.